# javascript to create an array with the repeating phrases in a text

Tags: javascript, jquery

The idea is simple: you put a text in textarea press "send" and return a list of the repeating phrases. By phrases i mean two or more word repeating. My problem is that i have no idea how to detect these (I can whit single words).

```
$(function() {
    $("#but").click(function() {
        var get = $("#inc").val();
        $("#res").html(get);
        return false;
    });
});
```

And the HTML:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <textarea name="inc" id="inc" spellcheck="false"></textarea> <br>
    <input type="submit" id="but" value="Send">
</form>

<div id="res"></div>
```

The problem is of course i dont know even where to start. Any ides?

Example:

> Paris s the capital and most populous city **of France**. Paris and the Paris region account for more than 30% of the gross domestic product **of France** and have one of the largest city GDPs in the world.

Comment: Could you explain your problem further? I am not able to get the phrases part

Comment: repeating as in "catcat dog" or as in "cat dog cat" ?

Comment: Hook on the submit event of the form, not on the click event of that one button!

Comment: I edited my question! in ex the "of France" is repeating.

Comment: @faq are these words coming form your text area... and what do you intend when you say repeating?

Comment: @faq Oh I get that now... thanks for editing

Comment: Just so you know, in terms of complexity, this task really heavy. For `n` words, you'll have to do `n(n(n-1))` comparisons, at least! We may be looking at a problem that require a custom data structure.

Comment: The effect as i sad it is simple: just return the phrases that are repeating.

Comment: @faq as mentioned by acdcjunior its not that simple. But could be done. I have added a link to some available solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout the http://brettterpstra.com/2011/11/02/word-repetition-checking-with-javascript/
This may be really helpful in what you are trying to do.Since the problem is not so very simple. It is better to have a look this blog post along with the solution given.
Its actually a word repetition script.

Answer (score 0):

[A quick search](http://www.google.de/search?q=detect+repetition+algorithm) will give you the idea that this is not a trivial problem :-)

Yet, for short examples as yours a brute-force approach may work, and keep the algorithm simple.

> I dont know even where to start. Any ideas?

The first thing is to split the text into words - removing whitespaces, punctuation marks etc. You will need to make a definition for the term "word" here, e.g. whether the `30%` should be counted as one.

Then build an array of minimal phrases - in your case, every two consecutive words. You might want to exclude those that originally had some punctuation in between.

Now, you can search for duplicates in that array of phrases - best by sorting it, and comparing successive items.

When you have found those repeating phrases, you can check for them whether you still find repetitions if you include more words.

Answer (score 0):

[I just wrote this JS Fiddle for fun](http://jsfiddle.net/heXn5/20/). I didn't really bother to check if something like it already exists, I wanted to write it. It should serve as an example.

Just enter a paragraph and press "analyze". It will give you the count of appearances of phrases composed by 2 or more words.

Have fun. :-)

That JS Fiddle contains this function:

```
function analyze_words() {
    document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = '';
    var registry = {};
    var text = document.getElementById('words_input').value;
    var words_splitted = text.split(/[\W]+/);
    var words = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < words_splitted.length; i++) {
        if (words_splitted[i].match(/\w/)) {
            words.push(words_splitted[i].toLowerCase());
        }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        var offset = i;
        var length = 1;
        while ((offset + length) < words.length) {
            var phrase = '';
            for (var x = offset; x <= (offset + length); x++) {
                phrase += words[x] + ' ';
            }
            phrase = phrase.replace(/\s$/, '');
            if (!(phrase in registry)) {
                registry[phrase] = 0;
            }
            registry[phrase]++;
            length++;
        }
    }
    for (var phrase in registry) {
        if (registry[phrase] > 1) {
           var div = document.createElement('div');
           div.innerHTML = '"' + phrase + '" appears ' + registry[phrase] + ' times.';
           document.getElementById('results').appendChild(div);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the text into words, generate [n-grams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram) from them and count which n-gram occurs the most - a piece of cake!

```
function ngrams(a, n) {
    return a.map(function(_, i) {
        return a.slice(i, i + n);
    }).slice(0, 1 - n);
}

function count(a) {
    return a.reduce(function(c, x) {
        c[x] = (c[x] || 0) + 1;
        return c;
    }, {});
}

function mostCommon(c) {
    return Object.keys(c).map(function(x) {
        return [x, c[x]]
    }).filter(function(a) {
        return a[1] > 1
    }).sort(function(a, b) {
        return b[1] - a[1]
    });
}
```

Example:

```
text = 
    "Paris is the capital of France. Paris is the most populous city of France. " + 
    "Most populous city of France is Paris, the capital of it " +
    "Another populous city of France is Lion";


words = text.toLowerCase().split(/\W+/g)
result = mostCommon(count(ngrams(words, 4)))
console.log(result)
```

Result:

```
[
 [
  "populous,city,of,france",  3
 ],
 [
  "most,populous,city,of",  2
 ],
 [
  "city,of,france,is",  2
 ]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r9Ht4/